# Is it good to place a recyclerview inside a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make an app in which I have added a Horizontal recycler view. I want to make a vertical list of Horizontal Recycler views.

Here, I am trying to make a list of the books of the different category, like I have added list of books in comics category which can be horizontally scrolled.
I wanted to add more such categories. I am trying to do so by making a recycler view inside a recycler view. Is this a right approach? If not!

[image]

what would be the best approach to do so?

Comment: I know it is ok since you see this behaviour in Google Play app, where you see horizontal recycler view, under each category

Comment: NO, its better use a dynamic layout consisting of linearLayout with UI elements

Comment: You could create a vertical recyclerview, with cells which has a horizontal recyclerview - then you just have to save the scrolloffset, whenever your cell is recycled, and set it back when the cell show again..  did it once, and it was awsome.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but if you want to nest recyclerview inside recyclerview then use this library:
Renderer RecyclerView Adapter, 
with Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.vivchar:RendererRecyclerViewAdapter:2.5.1'
}
```

and you may use it like this:

```
mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();

mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(new ViewBinder<>(
    R.layout.item_layout,
    SomeModel.class,
    (model, finder, payloads) -> finder
        .find(R.id.custom, (ViewProvider<CustomView>) customView -> { ... })
        .setBackground(R.id.image, model.getBackground())
        .setText(R.id.text, model.getText())
        .setOnClickListener(R.id.button, v -> { ... })
));
mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerRenderer(...); /* you can use several types of cells */

/* Regular code:
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);

mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(getItems());
mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
*/
```

And also have look at this [blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-handling-of-lists-rendererrecyclerviewadapter-part-2-3b18c8ea6f1b/)

Comment: *had to post it as an answer due to shortage reputation points* ==> please don't do that.

Comment: it's a stackoverflow problem...couldn't copy-paste someone else's code.